# How to overcome spacebar issue when using an adress in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Well, my user profile is named Mitrek Straszny (2 words), because of that everytime i try to use the command 'Start' in a batch file of something in my desktop(for instance) i get the message error saying that Windows could not find 'C:\Users\Mitrek.'. The error is obvious enough, is linked to the space bar, i have researched about it and found no awnsers yet.

I've also tried the enviroment variable %userprofile% it also doesn't work.

I first found this problem when trying this command line to change my wallpaper,

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d c:\users\Mitrek Straszny\Pictures\wallpaper.jpg
```

And yes, i also have tried

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d %userprofile%\Pictures\wallpaper.jpeg
```

Can anyone help-me? It seems a simple enough problem.

Answer (score 3):

Put it into quotation marks.

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d "c:\users\Mitrek Straszny\Pictures\wallpaper.jpg"
```